# PHP Variable and arrays, Client or serverside?

Tags: php

In the HEAD section of a page, mySQL data is loaded into a PHP array.

Where would this array data be stored, Client or Server-side?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side language, every php variable is in Server-side.

Answer (score 0):

php array will always be saved in server side.
you can print html, javascript using php. which can perform as clint side action later